# Inner class usage python. Global name is not defined

Tags: python

I have a question about inner classes usage in python. I know that this is a bad practice but anyway. I am wondering about scope where inner class is defined. I got an error 'global name 'ClassName' is not defined'. My code snippet looks like this:
[image]

I discovered that to avoid getting this error I can use:

```
ClassWithEnum.EnumClass
```

instead of:

```
EnumClass
```

inside of doSomethingWithEnum() function. So I am wondering if there is any other way to make EnumClass defined inside of doSomethingWithEnum() function? And why there is no such error when I declare EnumClass as a default parameter in doSomethingWithEnum() function?

Comment: Please post your code as code so it's easily copiable.

Comment: @deceze, Ok, will do so in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class ClassWithEnum(object):
    class EnumClass(object):
        ...

    def doSomethingWithEnum(self, m = EnumClass....):
        ...
```

Python class construction executes as code. The `def` statement is really a line of code being executed that creates a function. The `class` keyword introduces a namespace. Putting these two mechanisms together, it means that `class EnumClass` really creates an object by that name in the current namespace, not much different from what `foo = 'bar'` does, so within the same namespace you can refer to it by that name, which is what happens in the `def` statement.

Also compare:

```
class Foo:
    bar = 'baz'
    print bar
    baz = bar
```

Every line of code inside a `class` block is a regular executable line of code.

Once your `class` definition is done, you're out of the `ClassWithEnum` namespace and cannot access `EnumClass` anymore simply by that name; it's now only available as `ClassWithEnum.EnumClass`; whether from "outside" the class or from within a function (any function, including class methods).

To get access to the class without typing its name from within the method you could do:

```
type(self).EnumClass
```

Or simply `self.EnumClass`, since properties are looked up up the chain.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation and of course for this line `Python class construction executes as code`

Answer (score 2):

When you are inside `doSomethingWithEnum` function, you are in the different namespace. To access anything that is defined in your class, like `EnumClass`, you should call `self.EnumClass`. If it were a class method, it would be `cls.EnumClass`.